# AMFPHP service new service error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, amfphp

I am trying to add a new hello world service to amfphp, I am developing locally

```
<?php

/**
 * First tutorial class
 */
class HelloWorld {

   /**
    * first simple method
    * @returns a string saying 'Hello World!'
    */
   function sayHello()
   {
       return "Hello World!";
   }

}

?>
```

when exploring in the amfphp browser i get a 
    "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."
need help...

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for solving this type of problem, this let's you see what's going across the wire. In your case it's likely something simple as a syntax error in the php file. PHP will output the error information into what the Service Browser expects to be amf-encoded data, wreaking havoc to any parsing it tries. Using Charles you can easily see this and fix it!

Answer (score 1):

Is that the entirety of your source code? I'm sure this isn't the problem but just in case, you ***are*** opening the **?php** tag right?

Here's one of my simple service classes:

```
<?php

class Products {

    public function __construct() {
        mysql_connect("localhost", "myuser", "mypass");
        mysql_select_db("mydb");
    }
    /** 
    * Retrieves data
    * @returns data
    */
    function getProduct() {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `content_type_product`'; 
        return mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a variable/method that's null. The code here is fine so the problem is somewhere else..

Answer (score 0):

I agree with grapefrukt... The browser really doesn't give you good information about PHP errors. Charles is a godsend for doing stuff over AMF and I recommend it highly. You'll get information about the request and the result along with any PHP error messages.